# Phonegap1.6.1 is showing white screen when page loading or page changing in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

**Issue in Android 4.0.3**

1. I am using Phonegap 1.6.1.
2. jQuery Mobile 1.1.0

When the app is opened for the first time, or when the page transitions (page change), it shows a white screen.

If anybody has any idea or solution, please share with us.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [jQuery Mobile 1.1.1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/07/12/jqm-1-1-1/)? I think that is supposed to be one of the issues that was fixed

Comment: i tried using jquery mobile 1.1.1, but still same problem.

Comment: I too am having the same issue, across all devices/platforms. I'm running jquery 1.7.2 and jquery-mobile 1.1.1

Comment: how do you change a page if all you see is a white screen in the first place? a bit of code would definitely help here ;)

Comment: plz put data-ajax='false' where ever you calling next page ...